# AWS RDS (mysql) strange IO behavior

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I'm dealing with s db.r3.4xlarge RDS instance with 2000GB all purpose SSD (theoretically capable of up to 6000 IOPS), I'm restoring a bunch of table backup files of over 200GB. There are 26 simultaneous threads running, but Write IOPS is stuck at about 800. Queue depth is at 2 (give or take) and CPU is at 4-5%. Does this make sense? Why isn't the server using more IOPS available to it?

Answer (score 1):

In your DB Parameter Group change [innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit) from 1 to 0. This should speed up the writes since the default value writes completed transactions to the Redo Log Files (ib_logfile0, ib_logilfe1).

If you have binary logs enabled (when you enable Automated Backups), you can also change [sync_binlog](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_sync_binlog) from 1 to 0.

You will not need to reboot since these two options are dynamic.

When your restore is complete, set them back their original values ([innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit) back to 1, [sync_binlog](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_sync_binlog) back to 1).

Give it a Try !!!

## UPDATE 2018-02-02 14:27 EST

The only other thing I can think of would to increase the threads the CPUs use

If you look back at my 6.5 year old post [Possible to make MySQL use more than one core?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5666/possible-to-make-mysql-use-more-than-one-core/5670#5670), I mention the following options:

- [innodb_read_io_threads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_read_io_threads) (Reboot Required)

  - Default for MySQL 5.6 is `4`
  - Percona Server default is `8`
  - Please set this is `8`
- [innodb_write_io_threads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_write_io_threads) (Reboot Required)

  - Default for MySQL 5.6 is `4`
  - Percona Server default is `8`
  - Please set this to `8` or `16`
- [innodb_thread_concurrency](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_thread_concurrency) (Dynamic Option, Reboot Not Required)

  - Default for MySQL 5.6 is `0`
  - Make sure it is `0`
  - [Percona recommended using `64` if you are using MySQL 5.7](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/17/percona-server-5-7-performance-improvements/).

Comment: Thanks, but I already did that and it didn't make a difference

Comment: update - my instance had all the suggestions you made except for #of threads and thread concurrency which were default. I started another instance with the same exact configuration (leaving defaults in place) and it performed a lot better, though still didn't reach 6K throughput. I have a case open with AWS. will update as they get back to me.