# MySQL - Master/Slave Replication with different server specs

Tags: mysql, replication, innodb, mysql-5.1

I have a Master/Slave replication (using MySql 5.1 / InnoDB).

Currently both my master & slave are running on the same type of server (32 GB RAM, 2 x Intel Xeon 5520 Quad Core 2.26 GHz (8 cores)) and have the same type of configuration (in terms of innodb_pool_size etc.)

I am considering upgrading my master to a stronger machine (48GB RAM, 2 x Intel Xeon 5640 Six Core 2.26 GHz (12 cores)).

My question is: Is it possible to upgrade just the master (increase his buffer_bool_size etc.) and leave the slave at his current setup?

Comment: Just curious, what type of load does your slave handle. Is it just a load-balanced read server, or does it even handle traffic at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can upgrade the Master's my.cnf file to handle the new environment.

I have an additional suggestion.

InnoDB prior to MySQL 5.1.38 cannot use multiple CPUs.

You can do one of two things that will not affect the Slave

- Upgrade to Percona Server 5.1
- MySQL 5.1.38 has InnoDB Plugin (dsiabled by default) which acceses mulitple CPUs

  - If you have MySQL 5.1.37 or prior, upgrade to the latest MySQL 5.1 and install InnoDB Plugin
  - If you have MySQL 5.1.38+, install InnoDB Plugin

Once you do, one of the above, you can configure the necessary options for accessing multiple CPUs

- [About single threaded versus multithreaded databases performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2918/about-single-threaded-versus-multithreaded-databases-performance/2948#2948)
- [Possible to make MySQL use more than one core?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5666/possible-to-make-mysql-use-more-then-one-core/5670#5670)

Comment: by running `SELECT version();` i know that im running `5.1.61-0ubuntu0.11.10.1-log`. do I still need to upgrade / install the InnoDB plugin? or am I good to go?

Comment: Since you are using MySQL 5.1.61, you should install the InnoDB Plugin for InnoDB. Make sure it is there by running this Query : `SELECT * FROM mysql.plugin;`.

Comment: Are there any other, positive / negative replications for installing the plugin? Any good tutorial for installing the plugin?

Answer (score 1):

As long as your individual servers' settings don't exceed the capacity of the server (for things like memory usage), there is no problem with running different server specs. What I mean is that you don't copy the master's new configuration settings that utilize the 48GB RAM to the slave.

Answer (score 0):

If you are maxing out the Master, guess what will happen in the Slave?  It will get behinder and behinder.  That is, you *may* need the Slave to be at least as powerful as the Master.

Comment: Depends on what his slave is used for. In my case my slave is a very under-powered VM, that is only used for backups ( mysql dumps) and some long running background reports. Actual replication is not that resource intensive.

Comment: How did you decide on the specs for the underpowered VM? Is there a factor for CPU and RAM that you used (like 1/4 of master) or what specifically?